# How to make Location Services icon disappear from Status Bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

My application doesn't need location service to constantly monitor user's location and I really don't want to drain battery, so on startup I get the location, send it to statistics server and call `stopUpdatingLocation` on my `CLLocationManager` instance. Icon disappears from status bar! :)

Next, in one of my tabs I have `MKMapView` in which user can ask for and see (using annotation) his current location. After I switch to another tab with different view I'd like to stop using location services. How to achieve this? I've read SO question [What determines the presence of the iPhone Location Services icon in the status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413963/what-determines-the-presence-of-the-iphone-location-services-icon-in-the-status-b) and now I'm about to start thinking described use case is a bug in iOS (?).

**EDIT:** in view with `MKMapView` I don't use `CLLocationManager` at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `viewDidDisappear` method in the view controller that has the `MKMapView`, set the mapview's `showsUserLocation` property to NO.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
}
```

Comment: way too much coding yesterday for me - feel ashamed for not finding that easy solution myself ;) Thanks a lot!