# Why does the iPhone GPS arow appear in the status bar, even though I did not call startUpdatingLocation on the Location Manager?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

What can cause the GPS arrow to appear in the status bar, besides calling startUpdatingLocation or startUpdatingHeading on CLLocationManager?

Can it appear when you do any operation using CLLocationManager or CLLocation objects, such as calculating distance between two CLLocations?

If so, does this represent any power drain, as using the GPS would if you startUpdatingLocation?

Comment: maybe other apps use it?

Comment: Assume no other apps are using it.

Comment: visit this answer may be its helps to you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413963/what-determines-the-presence-of-the-iphone-location-services-icon-in-the-status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you instantiate CLLocationManager, and then call location on it, the GPS arrow will appear.