# iPhone shows location services as active even when not updating

Tags: ios, core-location, background-process

I am writing an iOS tracking app. The user may select within the app whether and when to enable tracking. I have verified that there is only one call to construct a single CLLocationManager object in the app's code, that it is only called once and that it is only constructed when tracking is enabled.

I cannot seem to prevent the app from showing the "tracking" icon in the iPhone's status bar or showing that it is currently tracking in [Settings => Privacy => Location Services]. I do have background location services enabled in the info.plist for the app, but I would not think that it should report that the app is tracking location when startUpdatingLocation or startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges have not been called and no instance of CLLocationManager has been instantiated.

I have tried restarting the phone, disabling and enabling location services and messed around with airplane mode and such with no success. Does the fact that the app supports background location updates mean that the user will always see that the app is getting location updates, even when it isn't?

Comment: It looks like I duped a question that I didn't find in my initial searches. The answer is that it appears to be a bug that can be fixed as described in the following link [Settings => General => Reset => Reset Location Warnings]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4414400/2487432